# Couldn't install QT5 base with VCPKG

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, vcpkg, github-codespaces

I decided to learn C++ GUI development with Qt5 using Visual Studio Code remotely (for personal preference) and from what I found in order to install Qt from command line, you need to use VCPKG file manager. But as I typed, `vcpkg/vcpkg install qt5-base` (previously I searched `vcpkg/vcpkg search qt` and found this package is present), it took really long to process and at the end this error message has pop up:

```
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_required_process.cmake:96 (message):
    Command failed: /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/buildtrees/qt5-base/src/5.15.5-451bf817fc.clean/configure -confirm-license -opensource -verbose -system-zlib -system-libjpeg -system-libpng -system-freetype -system-pcre -system-doubleconversion -system-sqlite -system-harfbuzz -icu -no-angle -no-glib -openssl-linked -no-sql-psql -no-sql-mysql --vulkan=no -fontconfig -xcb-xlib -xcb -linuxfb -nomake examples -nomake tests -static LIBJPEG_LIBS=/workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libjpeg.a ZLIB_LIBS=/workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libz.a "LIBPNG_LIBS=/workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libpng16d.a /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libz.a" PCRE2_LIBS=/workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libpcre2-16.a "FREETYPE_LIBS=/workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libfreetyped.a /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libbz2d.a /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libpng16d.a /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libz.a /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libbrotlidec-static.a /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libbrotlicommon-static.a" "ICU_LIBS=/workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libicui18n.a /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libicutu.a  /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libicuuc.a /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libicuio.a /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libicudata.a" QMAKE_LIBS_PRIVATE+=/workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libbz2d.a QMAKE_LIBS_PRIVATE+=/workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libpng16d.a "QMAKE_LIBS_PRIVATE+=/workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libicui18n.a /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libicutu.a  /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libicuuc.a /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libicuio.a /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libicudata.a" QMAKE_LIBS_PRIVATE+=/workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libzstd.a "SQLITE_LIBS=/workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libsqlite3.a -ldl -lpthread" "HARFBUZZ_LIBS=-lharfbuzz -lm -lfreetyped -lbz2d -lpng16d -lm -lz -lbrotlidec-static -lbrotlicommon-static" "OPENSSL_LIBS=/workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libssl.a /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libcrypto.a -ldl -lpthread" "FONTCONFIG_LIBS=/workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libfontconfig.a /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libfreetyped.a /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libexpat.a -luuid" -debug -prefix /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux -hostprefix /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/tools/qt5/debug -hostlibdir /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/tools/qt5/debug/lib -hostbindir /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/tools/qt5/debug/bin -archdatadir /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/tools/qt5/debug -datadir /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/share/qt5/debug -plugindir /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/plugins -qmldir /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/qml -headerdir /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include/qt5 -libexecdir /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/tools/qt5/debug -bindir /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/bin -libdir /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib -I /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include -I /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include/qt5 -L /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib -L /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/manual-link -platform linux-g++
    Working Directory: /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/buildtrees/qt5-base/x64-linux-dbg
    Error code: 3
    See logs for more information:
      /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/buildtrees/qt5-base/config-x64-linux-dbg-out.log
      /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/buildtrees/qt5-base/config-x64-linux-dbg-err.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  ports/qt5-base/cmake/configure_qt.cmake:127 (vcpkg_execute_required_process)
  ports/qt5-base/portfile.cmake:348 (configure_qt)
  scripts/ports.cmake:147 (include)


error: building qt5-base:x64-linux failed with: BUILD_FAILED
Please ensure you're using the latest port files with `git pull` and `vcpkg update`.
Then check for known issues at:
    https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+in%3Atitle+qt5-base
You can submit a new issue at:
    https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/new?template=report-package-build-failure.md&title=[qt5-base]+Build+error
Include '[qt5-base] Build error' in your bug report title, the following version information in your bug description, and attach any relevant failure logs from above.
    vcpkg-tool version: 2022-07-21-a0e87e227afb536c62188c11ad029954f28fdb22
    vcpkg-scripts version: e6a000679 2022-08-03 (33 hours ago)

You can also use the prefilled template from /workspaces/octopus-browser/vcpkg/installed/vcpkg/issue_body.md.
```

I have ensured I have both latest versions of VCPKG by running `git pull` and `vcpkg update`. In the process it threw me a few warnings:

```
CMake Warning at ports/qt5-base/portfile.cmake:4 (message):
  qt5-base currently requires some packages from the system package manager,
  see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-requirements.html
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  scripts/ports.cmake:147 (include)


CMake Warning at ports/qt5-base/portfile.cmake:5 (message):
  qt5-base for qt5-x11extras requires several libraries from the system
  package manager.  Please refer to

    https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/scripts/azure-pipelines/linux/provision-image.sh
    for a complete list of them.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  scripts/ports.cmake:147 (include)
```

The reason why I cannot use the official installer is because I run it on GitHub Codespaces and cannot install anything there manually, only using the command prompt. What can I do to resolve this issue and what are the alternative ways to install QT if there are any?

Comment: Are you sure you have all required system packages installed?